# Rails request parameters ignored when anchor present

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

I have a request coming into my rails 3 application:

```
http://mydomain/controller/action#an_anchor?p1=1&p2=2&p3=3
```

my route:

```
match '/controller/:action' => 'controller'
```

Routing successfully finds my controller and action, but params is empty.  (Well almost empty, params contains controller and action but none of the passed in params).

It's as though everything on the url following # was stripped out.  I would expect the system to ignore #...?, but still give my query parameters.

I also tried this route:

```
match '/controller/*stuff' => 'controller'
```

and 'stuff' is in the params up to the # .  Everything after the # is gone including url parameters.

Is this a bug? Is there *any* way to pass an anchor tag in a url and still extract the query parameters?

(Addition:) This url is coming from PayPal as part of their embedded shopping cart. I have no control over the order of the fields on the String and I can't be the only person to be using a paypal mini-cart.  The actual url values are:

.../paypal#PPMiniCart=reset?tx=4NH71321AG6850224&st=Completed&amt=2.73&cc=USD

Answer (score 4):

Everything after the # is stripped out - the browser does not send fragment part of the URL to the server.

If you want those parameters to be treated as part of the query string they must be before the #

Comment: Yep. IE. the params are not stripped out, but they are interpreted as being part of the anchor. Your computer sees the anchor as `an_anchor?p1=1&p2=2&p3=3`